# Jenkins job unable to push tar files to s3 bucket

Tags: jenkins, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam

I created one jenkins job to backup jenkins home directory to one S3 bucket.

Script for this job:

```
echo 'tar $JENKINS_HOME directory'
set +e 
tar -cvf jenkins_backup.tar -C /var/lib/jenkins .
exitcode=$?
if [ "$exitcode" != "1" ] && [ "$exitcode" != "0" ]; then
exit $exitcode
fi
set -e
echo 'Upload jenkins_backup.tar to S3 bucket'
aws s3 cp jenkins_backup.tar s3://jenkins.xxxx.xxxx/
echo 'Remove files after succesful upload to S3'
rm -rf *
```

ERROR:

```
+ aws s3 cp jenkins_backup.tar s3://jenkins.xxx.xxx/
upload failed: ./jenkins_backup.tar to s3://jenkins.xxxx.xxxxx/jenkins_backup.tar An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the CreateMultipartUpload operation: Access Denied
```

I checked IAM role(attached full S3 permissions policy), default region and I am able to run s3 commands locally from jenkins ec2 server but jenkins job is failing. Not sure what causing this issue. Please suggest.

thank you

Comment: What about the bucket policy? Those trump IAM roles. It's possible there's an explicit DENY there

Comment: Also what version of aws cli are you running? This used to be a bug earlier. So long as your awscli is newer version, you should be able to upload with proper IAM role and bucket policy.

Check the below as well.

1. Increase your triggering limit for s3 cp command from the default 8MB to higher, e.g. 5GB (see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/topic/s3-config.html)

1. Use aws s3api put-object instead - it doesn't automatically switch to multi-part uploads.

Comment: @danielC and MO:  Bucket doesnt have any deny policies. I am able run this command "aws s3 cp jenkins_backup.tar s3://jenkins.xxxx.xxxx/" from jenkins server(Logging into EC2 server ). My question is how come i am able to run aws cli commands from jenkins ec2 server but not from jenkins build job? 
BTW my jenkins jobs are running directly from master server, i am not using any slaves